# Аналог urllib.parse.urlencode для urllib3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

Есть код для библиотеки urllib:

```
enc_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(polo_data).encode()
```

Не могу найти в urllib3 urlencode. Каким должен быть аналог этого кода для urllib3?

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу в [urllib3 докуметации](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide.html#query-parameters), что в примере используется всё тот же `urllib.parse.urlencode`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
encoded_args = urlencode({'arg': 'value'})
```

Comment: Да, похоже, что в urllib3 нет аналога urlencode, по крайней мере в документации ничего похожего не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

```
 urllib3.util.parse_url(url)
```

более подробно можно поискать тут: [urllib3.util.parse_url](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.parse_url)

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Все дело в том, что в качестве передаваемого параметра передается dict. При использовании ```urllib3.util.parse_url``` получаю ошибку **'dict' object has no attribute 'find'**

Comment: проверь какие есть вообще ключи "dict.keys()"

Comment: да, и такой вопрос, какую цель ты преследуешь? я имею в виду, какую информацию ты хочешь получить и что ты планируешь с ней делать

Comment: Ключи есть.  Не поустой словарь приходит. Цель следующая: получить строку в формате: **b'param1=value1&param2=value2'** У меня проект весь написан на urllib3 (достался по наследству). Хоть вручную строку формируй...

Comment: ну, наследство бывает разное и часто не приходится перебирать... вручную тоже не вариант, особенно когда вариантов только одной переменной может быть много... могу предложить такой вариант, словарь поддерживает быстрый поиск "in". ты можешь попробовать проверять какя из возможных переменных есть по факту, на а потом собирать строку по кусочкам. и если чего-либо не будет, то пропускать. это конечно внесёт в код много проверок, зато ты не будешь для пользователя сам генерировать каждую строку с адресом

Comment: Верно. Только так и остается, видимо, сделать. Надеялся, что в urllib3 есть аналог parse. Спасибо за попощь :)